# Set header in node https

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, gitlab, header

I have a problem to set the header with `https.get` function.

I need to access a file with the gitlab API that requires a header like this:

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects"`

How can I set the header like that?

I've already tred:

```
const options = {
    hostname: 'gitlab.example.com',
    path: '/api/v4/projects',
    headers: {
        "PRIVATE-TOKEN": "<your_access_token>"
    }
}

https.get(options, (resp) => {
    ...
})
```

or

```
const options = {
    hostname: 'gitlab.example.com',
    path: '/api/v4/v4/projects',
    headers: "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>"
}

https.get(options, (resp) => {
    ...
})
```

or

```
const options = {
    hostname: 'gitlab.example.com',
    path: '/api/v4/projects',
    headers: {
        "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>":""
    }
}

https.get(options, (resp) => {
    ...
})
```

In this 2 cases the response is not correct

Answer (score 0):

***1. Using HTTP.get request***

In Node.js, when you're using the **https.get** function, you should provide an object for the headers field where each header field is a separate key-value pair.

Example:

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'gitlab.example.com',
  path: '/api/v4/projects',
    headers: {
      'PRIVATE-TOKEN': '<your_access_token>'
    }
}

https.get(options, (resp) => {

  var result = ''
  resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
    result += chunk;
  });

  resp.on('end', function () {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

});

***2. Using Axios***

You can use **Axios** to make HTTP requests in Node.js, including requests to the GitLab API with custom headers.

```
const axios = require('axios');

const gitlabUrl = 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects';
const accessToken = '<your_access_token>';

const config = {
  headers: {
    'PRIVATE-TOKEN': accessToken
  }
};
```

NOTE: Please Remeber to replace **'<your_access_token>'** with your actual GitLab access token